# How can I programmatically change the default system keyboard to a custom keyboard in a Flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have created my custom keyboard using the Flutter framework and I used it for my app but I need to use this custom keyboard as a system keyboard to use it for other apps in any phone.

I have a few questions regarding the implementation:

1. What is the recommended approach for changing the default system keyboard to a custom keyboard in a Flutter app?
2. Are there platform-specific considerations or best practices when implementing a custom keyboard for both Android and iOS platforms?
3. How can I programmatically hide the system keyboard and show my custom keyboard when a particular input field is focused?
4. What Flutter packages or methods can be used to manage the input mode or keyboard type on both Android and iOS?
5. Are there any potential challenges or limitations associated with changing the default system keyboard?